# How do I use aiohttp efficiently?

Tags: python, performance, python-requests, aiohttp

I've been using requests for a while and finally decided to convert my code to be async/aiohttp friendly. I think I've botched up the usage somewhere considering it's performance.

I've attached a small piece of the most used functions, the first two being aiohttp friendly while the others using requests for the same thing. The time difference is HUGE, aiohttp is so much slower than requests.

```
import aiohttp
import requests
import asyncio

async def returnUUID(ign=None):
  try:
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
      async with session.get(f"https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/{ign}") as resp:
        x= await resp.json()
        return x["id"]
  except:
    return 'notfound'

async def returnRank(ign=None):
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get("https://api.hypixel.net/guild?key=key_here&id=5e8c16788ea8c9ec75077ba2") as resp:
      x = await resp.json()
      y = x["guild"]["members"]
      for user in y:
        #user = dict(user)
        if user["uuid"] == await returnUUID(ign):
          return user["rank"]

def MS(ign=None):
  uuid = UUID(ign)
  try:
    members = requests.get('https://api.hypixel.net/guild?key=key_here&id=5e8c16788ea8c9ec75077ba2').json()["guild"]["members"]
    for member in members:
      if member["uuid"] == uuid:
         return True
      else:
        continue
  except:
    return False

def UUID(ign=None):
  try:
    return requests.get(f"https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/{ign}").json()["id"]
  except:
    return "`UUID not found`"

def Rank(ign=None):
  if MS(ign) is True:
    uuid = UUID(ign)
    members = requests.get('https://api.hypixel.net/guild?key=key_here&id=5e8c16788ea8c9ec75077ba2').json()["guild"]["members"]
    for member in members:
      if member["uuid"] == uuid:
        return str(member["rank"])
```

Functions starting with return are async friendly while the ones without, are the requests counterpart. I converted my entire codebase to aiohttp (600+ lines for this project), and it's become so much slower. I timed it using the timeit library, and there's almost an 8-second difference between aiohttp and requests (requests being faster). Isn't aiohttp supposed to be more efficient and faster?

Comment: Why do you think the async version should be *faster*? And what do you mean by *faster*? Async workflows can improve IO bound bottlenecks by preventing a thread from waiting on other IO tasks, but they don’t make individual tasks faster. Without more context there’s no way to answer this.

Comment: By faster I mean in terms of speed, requests takes 0.4 seconds to do what aiohttp did in 9. I understand that aiohttp isn't blocking and lets other processes run while it waits for the response but at the least, it should match request's speed.

Comment: I want to know either -
- Why aiohttp is so much slower than requests
- How I can use aiohttp efficiently, like the best practices and the fastest ways (in terms of speed, not coding)

Comment: It might help to show the code you use to measure this.

Comment: I used timeit, 
```
import timeit
print("Requests",timeit.timeit(stmt='from main import *;Rank("TheOnlyWayUp")'))
print("aiohttp",timeit.timeit(stmt='from main import *;loop = asyncio.get_event_loop();loop.run_until_complete(returnRank("TheOnlyWayUp"))'))
```
But you can also use
```
import time
start_time = time.time()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(returnRank("TheOnlyWayUp"))
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: How do I format code in comments?

Comment: You aren't comparing the correct things. You need to compare downloading resources concurrently with asyncio vs sequentially with requests. Your test is setting up an event loop, then requesting a single url in *each loop of the test*. *Or course* that's slower. The power of asyncio comes when you can do requests concurrently rather than in sequence. To test that you will need make a function that downloads a bunch of urls at once. (p.s. you can't put code in comments — better off editing the question)

Answer (score -1):

Try Pycurl with background thread, it's ~50% faster than requests .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).